# ReactJS; navigate to a 'dynamic' data-generated new page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have the main page, which presents a lot of items. I'm aiming to make each item clickable, which takes you to the item page. The caveat is there's a LOT of items (think tens of thousands) so I'm not going to hard code a new page for each one; the page should be auto-generated from item data (passed from the main page, or obtained from the DB, doesn't really matter).

If items were books, I'd want it to look something like this; `website.com/book/ReactJS For Dummies`. Now books can have different editions, which affects what data is shown on the page, so I need to pass an extra parameter through; something like `website.com/book/ReactJS For Dummies?edition=First_Edition`.

I've tried googling for reactJS solutions to this, but they all seem to involve react-router and static links to existing pages, not something dynamic like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently what I was looking for was React-Router's path props, as follows:

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    <Route path="/book/:bookName/:bookEdition" component={Book}/>
</Router>
```

Then I can wrap any component in a `Link`:

```
<Link to={"/book/ReactJS For Dummies/1st Edition"}><p>Link here</p></Link>
```

And in the `Book` component I can access those props via `this.props.params.bookName` and `this.props.params.bookEdition`. Pretty nifty.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that it would be better to have a unique key assigned to each book and then pass the key as a parameter,  that way edition is a non issue,  it's just another book.  Kind of like barcodes.  So you'd have

`website.com/book/1` as React for Dummies 1st edition and then

`website.com/book/2` as React for Dummies 2nd edition

Passing an ID as a parameter would be much simpler than book names with other queries attached

Comment: I did consider that as an option, but for my particular design it's better to have the URL contain the book info in plaintext.